# Editing text outside of certain apps

Tags: typing

When i edit text outside of websites and browsers, instead of seeing the regular black line in front of the last letter, i see a big black block that spills over to following characters and makes them negative. It is weird and makes editing text in between other text very difficult and uncomfortable.

[image]

Comment: It's normally an Insert key issue, if you are seeing ▊ instead of | but that doesn't sound quite the same. Can you get a screenshot.

Comment: you're right, that is what i see, here's a screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/vFCwEo0

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing ▊ instead of | press your Insert key.